# iOS: show segue prevents UITableViewController to auto scroll when UITextField gets focus

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a UITableViewController that is presented via a show (push) segue. Its rows have UITextFields. On the iPhone, when a textfield get focus, the keyboard hides the textfield if said textfield is towards the bottom of the screen.

This only happens on the iPhone, with any segue except "present modally" or "present as popover" ones. For these latter segues, the table scrolls up the textfield so that it's not covered by the keyboard - the standard behavior for UITableViewController.

On the iPad it works as expected (auto-scrolling the table), regardless of the segue type. Any idea why?

I've created a new project just to test this, it works as expected. In the initial project where it doesn't work, the UITableViewController is a secondary controller of a SplitViewController.

I've tested with or without auto-layout, same results.

iOS8

[image]

[image]

Thanks

The first screenshot shows the table with no textfield having focus
The second one was taken after the last textfield got focus. It is covered by the keyboard.

PS: I've tried the same with just a UITableViewController, not a subclass of UITableViewController as initially. I know in subclasses there is a problem if for example you override viewWillAppear but do not call super. This is not the case.

Relevant Apple documentation excerpt:

Note: A table view controller supports inline editing of table view rows; if, for example, rows have embedded text fields in editing mode, it scrolls the row being edited above the virtual keyboard that is displayed. It also supports the NSFetchedResultsController class for managing the results returned from a Core Data fetch request.

The UITableViewController class implements the foregoing behavior by overriding loadView, viewWillAppear:, and other methods inherited from UIViewController. In your subclass of UITableViewController, you may also override these methods to acquire specialized behavior. If you do override these methods, be sure to invoke the superclass implementation of the method, usually as the first method call, to get the default behavior.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW7

Comment: Please state a bit more clearly what the problem is! Is it that sometimes the keyboard hides the selected TextField and sometimes not? And you simulate 4 cases here, iPhone vs. iPad AND modal vs. show: in what case combination happens what exactly?

Comment: Screenshots please? Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @UttamSinha - added screenshots, thanks

Comment: @luk2302 -  I've modified the text, clarified the issues you ask about. Thanks

Comment: @johnnyMac - doesn't seems like its an issue of show or present modally. Just now checked my own, tableview scrolling up when last row textfield get focus. You need to check tableview frame & content size. If you are using autolayout then you have to check layout constraint.

Comment: @UttamSinha - if it's not a segue type issue, why is it working when segue is of modal or popover type?

Comment: @johnnyMac - is this issue you are facing in iphone 6 ios 8 and up? If yes then I have solution for this.

Comment: @UttamSinha - it's an iOS8 only project. Haven't tried iPhone 5s but I will, I assume it's going to behave the same way, will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the behaviour and faced this kind of issue in iPhone 6.

In viewDidLoad method -

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Thanks @UttamSinha. This is what I'm trying to avoid, it should just work without any of this.

Comment: One simple approach is write this in viewDidLoad - self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; This will work as expected :)

Comment: @johnnyMac - So tableview is scrolling up or not? I have added this in viewDidLoad and it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't scroll :(

Comment: Oh strange. I have checked with both keyboard notification event and above code. Both worked for me. Are you using autolayout? If yes then check constraint.

Comment: This must be a bug in Apple's implementation, it makes no sense for it to work only for certain segue types.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could tell you why the code below works, but I can't; I am aware that makes this a bad answer. With that said, it does work consistently across my application.

Add a simple completion block to your view controller dismissal. In my code, that means the viewWillAppear is called twice, once before dismissal and once after (as I said, I don't know why this works but it does for me).

`dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { self.viewWillAppear(true) }`